# A good name for ValueObject that contains database update/create column values

Tags: design, naming, value-object

We all know these fields, database admins so like to add:

- UserCreated & DateCreated
- UserUpdated & DateUpdated

They need to be displayed in the UI so I want to put them in some `ValueObject` but I can't come up with a good name to call the class...

Comment: Something like `UpdateInfo` or `CreateAndUpdateInfo`?

Comment: I was looking for something semantically meaningful but I'll go with `CreateAndUpdateInfo`, thanks :)

Comment: what if later you need to add more values, i propose you pick MetaInformations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DBA insists on these fields because he/she wants to ensure that the user and date of the last change is recorded.  This sort of tracking is called *audit*, and the history of these changes is an *audit trail*.

So how about `AuditInfo`?